# how to store database fields in a single vector

Tags: c++

I am fetching 6 fields from a database. Currently I am using structure. I want to store the database fields in a single vector. Is it possible through a vector of objects? If yes, how?

I have more than 70,000 rows in the database. I fetched it and stored inside a temp table, like this:

```
// select statement to fetch from temp_table. for example select * from temp_table 

while(cursor.fetch())
{
cursor >> field;

cout<<field;
}
```

Will it be efficient to store in a structure or vector in the while loop and print it, or is the above method fine?

Comment: What database library are you using?

Comment: For a more accurate answer we need to know what is `cursor`

Comment: ignore the code.. just in general, which will be efficient? using a select statement from temp table and printing it  or populated it to a vector and printing through loop